# Routh stability calculator algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Im trying to write algorithm for routh stability criterion, I load inputs into array then I try to calculate other values with algorithm. But Im struggling with that algorithm

this is what I have right now:

```js
function parse() {
  var str = document.getElementById("input").value;

  var n = str.split(/[-+]/).length;
  console.log(n);

  var x = [];
  x = str.split(/[-+]/);

  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    if (x[i].charAt(0) == "s") {
      a[i] = 1;
    } else {
      a[i] = Number(x[i].charAt(0));
    }
  }

  i = 0;

  console.log(a[0]);
  console.log(a[1]);
  console.log(a[2]);
  console.log(a[3]);

  var k = [];

  k[0] = a[0] / a[1];

  var b = [];

  for (i; i < n - 2; i++) {

    b[i] = a[i + 2] - (k[i] * a[i + 3]); // a[i+3] is undefined 
    k[i + 1] = a[i + 1] / b[i];

    console.log(b[0]);
    console.log(b[1]);
    console.log(k[0]);
    console.log(k[1]);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input" id="input">
<button onclick="parse()">calculate</button>
```

Values in blue I have and values in red I need, I dont know how to define when there is no more values in array to calculate next line.

[routh criterion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evvI5.png)

Comment: my input looks like this:
s^3+4s^2+4s+8